# Is memory alignment processor dependent or data dependent or cache line length dependent?

Tags: c, caching, double, memory-alignment

I am dynamically declaring an `array of doubles` in `C` targeted for `Intel Sandy Bridge E5-2670` processor which has a `cache line size of 64 bytes` using `_mm_malloc()`.

My questions are:

1. Should the array be `8 byte aligned` (i.e. size of double) ?
2. Should the array be `64 byte aligned` because of cache line size of 64 bytes ?
3. Should the array be `32 byte aligned` (mentioned in a paper by *Saini et. al.* for AVX instructions) ?

Comment: Unless you have some special requirement (e.g. using SIMD, or you need every last percent of available performance) then the default 8 byte alignment is fine.

Comment: @PaulR : Yes I would like to use SIMD vectorisation, maximise performance and very importantly understand data alignment. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: OK, so 16 byte alignment for SSE then, 32 byte alignment for AVX, AVX2 (not required, but it makes life easier and can make a small difference in performance).

Comment: @PaulR: That means alignment is always processor dictated. Thanks !

Comment: More or less - I would say it's dictated more by overall *architecture*, assuming you're looking at performance as well as absolute requirements.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so 16 byte alignment for SSE then, 32 byte alignment for AVX, AVX2 (not required, but it makes life easier and can make a small difference in performance). – Paul R